# Can't launch AVD in emulator Permission denied

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am developing an android app for my project. When I tried to launch my emulator it gave me that error.

[image: Error: Please click here]

Comment: Did it (or any other AVD) used to work?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Seems to be a Windows permission issue like you need to run as an administrator. Personally, I use Genymotion emulator and have no problems with it.

Comment: Yeah Restarted the system but it was showing same thing@Stephan

Answer (score 1):

I don't know will it work but try to Quit Android Studio and run it in Administrator mode if you're in windows.

Comment: It's not working again showing error which i got earlier.